# sum all rows with join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

How to sum all rows in a query with a join?

```
SELECT SUM(accounting.amount) AS sum, SUM(balance_invoice.amount) AS sum_balance
FROM accounting
LEFT JOIN balance_invoice ON balance_invoice.accounting_id=accounting.id
```

I need this query to return only one row with the total sum of `accounting.amount` and `balance_invoice.amount`

Multiple rows can be joined to each `accounting.id`

## update

```
SELECT SUM(accounting.currency_amount*-1 + (
    SELECT SUM(balance_invoice_accounting.currency_amountoff)
    FROM balance_invoice_accounting
    WHERE balance_invoice_accounting.accounting_id=accounting.id
)) AS sum
FROM accounting
```

Comment: please see my updated answer. i'd drop the join and use a subselect instead.

Comment: Is that update of yours an answer? If so, it should be posted as an answer, not an update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

just add both values inside of the `SUM()`-function:

```
SELECT SUM(accounting.amount + balance_invoice.amount) AS sum_all
FROM accounting
LEFT JOIN balance_invoice ON balance_invoice.accounting_id=accounting.id
```

if one of the columns can be `NULL`, you should add an additional [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT
SUM(COALESCE(accounting.amount,0) + COALESCE(balance_invoice.amount,0) AS sum_all
FROM accounting
LEFT JOIN balance_invoice ON balance_invoice.accounting_id=accounting.id
```

**EDIT:**
i'm sorry i missed that important part. if you want to count every `accounting.amount` only once while there can be multiple `balance_invoice.amount` joined to it, i'd use a subselect like this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  (
    a.amount
    + 
    (SELECT SUM(b.amount) FROM balance_invoice b WHERE b.accounting_id = a.id)
  ) AS sum_all
FROM
  accounting a
```

Comment: ok, but does this also work if you have multiple joins to each accounting.id?